# c# webbrowser javascript handle file download and save file without dialog

Tags: javascript, c#, web-crawler, webbrowser-control

I want to download a file that is generated by javascript when I click on the link.
target page http://portal.dls.gov.ua/PublicSite/TradeLicense/TradeLicenseList.aspx
than i use a code to navigate:

```
//set filter
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00$Content$fvParams$edtLicName").SetAttribute("value", "наша");
//apply filter
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Content_fvParams_UpdateButton").InvokeMember("Click");
//click export button
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_Content_hlExport1").InvokeMember("Click");
```

after clicking on the button opens the file save dialog
i dont have direct url to file.
but i know file name, it is always "PUB_TradeLicense.xls"
how to prevent save dialog opening and donwload file silently?

Comment: that sounds sketchy...

Comment: If you can't access it directly with a Url then you can't do what you're asking, for obvious security reasons.